# merging a series of vectors into one sequentially in clojure

Tags: vector, clojure, functional-programming

I have a program which performs a search to Amazon and returns information on the specified book. Once all the searches are performed I wanted to be able to sort the books by SalesRank. The problem that i'm having is being able to combine the vectors into one large collection. Right now I can get them to print one by one but each iteration overwrites the previous. I'm a functional programming NOOB so any help is appreciated. Below is a snippet:

```
(defn get_title_and_rank_for_one_isbn [isbn]

        (def book_title (get-in (amazon_search isbn)[:items 0 :item-atributes :title]))
        (def sales_rank(get-in (amazon_search isbn)[:items 0 :SalesRank]))
        (def book_isbn(get-in (amazon_search isbn)[:items 0 :asin]))

)

(defn get_title_and_rank_for_all_isbns [list_of_isbns]
    (doseq [isbn list_of_isbns] 
        (Thread/sleep 3000)
        (get_title_and_rank_for_one_isbn isbn)
        (def combine_attributes(reduce into [[book_title] [book_isbn] [sales_rank]]))
        (println combine_attributes)
    )

)
```

Comment: This is pretty clearly the same question you posted a couple hours ago.  You don't repost under a new account name on SO.  Kindly delete this question before it gets closed for you.  Someone will help you out in due time.  In the meantime, keep working on your problem yourself.  Maybe get a book.

Comment: You may want to start here:  http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/getting_started.html

Comment: @jmargolisvt I dont have any other accounts. can you link me to the other post? perhaps it's a class mate.

Comment: It's the previous question on the clojure tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513290/i-want-to-keep-adding-to-a-list-in-clojure.  If no one else answers in the next few hours, I'll post something tonight on the other question to get you guys going.  In the meantime... this is a class?  Get out the textbook! :)

Comment: Seems like the other guy deleted his post.

Comment: For these kinds of problems it is always helpful to include the exact input (in this case the return value of `amazon_search`, and the wanted output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defn- get-books [data]
  (letfn [(one-book [book]
            (let [title (get-in book :title)
                  rank (get-in book :rank)
                  isbn (get-in book :isbn)]
                {:title title
                 :rank rank
                 :isbn isbn}))]
            (map one-book data))))
```

There are probably several ways to do this, but this is one take with some simplified code.  You might call the function like this: `(println (get-books data))` Where `data` is your json structure.

So what's happening in `get-books`?  `leftn` allows you to define functions which you can encapsulate here.  Clojure functions will return the last thing defined, in this case, it's the `map` function.  In fact, it's pretty much the only thing that "runs" here.  It maps your data over the `one-book` function which uses `let` to create bindings that are re-bound as each book passes through the function.  This takes the place of your thinking about using `def`.

Again, `one-book` returns its last definition which is a key-value structure. You map over all the data then print it out, pass it to another function, or whatever you need to do with it.

This is less an exact solution than it is a suggestion for how to think about processing your data and how to return values from a function.

Comment: Wow! That is a great template and gives me a much better idea on how to perform tasks in Clojure. I really appreciate you taking the time to give such a detailed answer.

Comment: Sure thing. A proper SO thank you would be accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First observe that `(amazon_search isbn)` should only run once per isbn.

Then [map](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/map) over each search result independently and extract the desired data into new maps that you finally sort by sales rank.

```
 (defn get-book [isbn]
   (let [itm (get-in (amazon_search isbn) [:items 0])]
     {:book/title (get-in itm [:item-attributes :title])
      :book/sales-rank (:SalesRank itm)
      :book/isbn (:asim itm)}))

 (defn get-books-sorted-by-sales-rank [isbns]
    (->> isbns (map get-book) (sort-by :book/sales-rank)))

 ;; a bit more performant
```